# Ways to Speed Up This Script for Returning Google Docs Files Modified in Current Year

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm currently using the following script to return only Google Docs files that were modified in the current year. It recursively runs through folders and sub folders within a Shared Drive and returns the results in a Google Sheets file. It does the job, but it runs somewhat slow. I'm just curious if there's anything I could do to modify this script to make it run quicker. Thanks for your help!

```
function listGoogleDocsModifiedInCurrentYear() {
  var folderId = "SHARED FOLDER ID HERE"; 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  
  var sheetYear = getOrCreateSheet(spreadsheet, currentYear + " Docs");
  sheetYear.clearContents(); // Clear existing data in the sheet
  
  var headersRange = sheetYear.getRange("A1:F1");
  var headersValues = headersRange.getValues();
  var headersApplied = headersValues[0][0] === "Last Modified";
  
  if (!headersApplied) {
    sheetYear.getRange("A1:F1").setValues([["Last Modified", "Title", "Type", "Link", "Last Modifier", "Folder Name"]]);
    sheetYear.getRange("A1:F1").setFontWeight("bold");
    sheetYear.getRange("A1:F1").setHorizontalAlignment("left");
    sheetYear.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  
  var processedFiles = new Set();
  
  listGoogleDocsModifiedInCurrentYearRecursive(folder, sheetYear, processedFiles, function(fileDataArray) {
    if (fileDataArray.length > 0) {
      
      sheetYear.getRange(sheetYear.getLastRow() + 1, 1, fileDataArray.length, fileDataArray[0].length).setValues(fileDataArray);
    }
  });
}

function listGoogleDocsModifiedInCurrentYearRecursive(folder, sheetYear, processedFiles, callback) {
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  var folderFileNames = new Set(); // Set to store file names within the folder
  
  var existingData = sheetYear.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < existingData.length; i++) {
    folderFileNames.add(existingData[i][1]);
  }
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    var fileName = file.getName();
  
    if (processedFiles.has(fileId) || folderFileNames.has(fileName)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    var fileLink = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + fileId + "/view";
    var fileDate = file.getLastUpdated();
    
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    if (fileDate.getFullYear() === currentYear) {
      var lastModifierEmail = getLastModifierEmail(fileId);
      var folderName = (folder.getName() === "root") ? getSharedDriveName(file) : folder.getName();
      var fileType = "Google Doc";
      
      var fileDataArray = [
        [fileDate, fileName, fileType, fileLink, lastModifierEmail, folderName]
      ];
      callback(fileDataArray);
      
      processedFiles.add(fileId);
      folderFileNames.add(fileName);
    }
  }
  
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder = subfolders.next();
    listGoogleDocsModifiedInCurrentYearRecursive(subfolder, sheetYear, processedFiles, callback);
  }
}

function getLastModifierEmail(fileId) {
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  
  if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = revisions.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var lastModifier = revisions.items[i].lastModifyingUser;
      if (lastModifier && lastModifier.emailAddress) {
        return lastModifier.emailAddress;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return "No modifier";
}
```

Comment: `It does the job, but it runs somewhat slow` Would you please describe your definition of "somewhat slow", how many folders and files are you retrieving, what research you did before asking this question and/or what you have already tried.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected situation, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, how about retrieving the file list using the search query instead of `getFilesByType`? By this, the Google Document files updated this year can be directly retrieved.
- In order to retrieve the modified user's email, how about using the batch request? When the batch request is used, the process cost can be reduced a little. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script?hl=en)
- In your script, at `sheetYear.clearContents(); // Clear existing data in the sheet`, it seems that the sheet is cleared. In this case, I thought that `if (!headersApplied) {}` might not be able to be used.
- `sheetYear.getRange("A1:F1")` can be used one time.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Usage:

##### 1. Install Google Apps Script library

In this case, in order to use the batch request, please install the Google Apps Script library. [Ref (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)

You can see how to install this at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install).

##### 2. Enable Drive API

Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

##### 3. Sample script

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Please set your folder ID.
  const folderId = "SHARED FOLDER ID HERE"; 


  // Retrieve file list.
  const getDocFiles_ = (folder, q, obj = new Map()) => {
    if (folder) {
      const files = folder.searchFiles(q);
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        const file = files.next();
        const name = file.getName();
        if (!obj.has(name)) {
          const fileId = file.getId();
          let folderName = file.getParents().next().getName();
          // folderName = (folderName === "root") ? getSharedDriveName(file) : folderName; // I'm not sure whether you use this line.
          obj.set(name, { value: [file.getLastUpdated(), name, "Google Docs", `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${fileId}/view`, "", folderName], fileId });
        }
      }
      const subFolders = folder.getFolders();
      while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
        getDocFiles_(subFolders.next(), q, obj);
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const thisYear = new Date();
  thisYear.setMonth(0);
  thisYear.setDate(1);
  thisYear.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  thisYearStr = thisYear.toISOString();
  const q = `mimeType='${MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}' and trashed=false and modifiedDate >= '${thisYearStr}'`;
  const values = [...getDocFiles_(folder, q).values()];
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  const requests = {
    batchPath: "batch/drive/v3",
    requests: values.map(({ fileId }) => ({
      method: "GET",
      endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?supportsAllDrives=true&fields=lastModifyingUser(emailAddress)`
    }))
  };
  const result = BatchRequest.EDo(requests); // Using this library
  const res = values.map(({ value }, i) => (value[4] = result[i].lastModifyingUser?.emailAddress || null, value));

  // Put values to the sheet.

  // This is from your script.
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  var sheetYear = getOrCreateSheet(spreadsheet, currentYear + " Docs");

  sheetYear.getRange("A1:F1").setValues([["Last Modified", "Title", "Type", "Link", "Last Modifier", "Folder Name"]]).setFontWeight("bold").setHorizontalAlignment("left");
  sheetYear.setFrozenRows(1);
  sheetYear.getRange(2, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

##### Testing

When I tested this modified script, I confirmed the same result as your showing script. In my test, the process cost could be reduced by about 40 %.

#### References:

- [Batch details](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance#details)
- [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)